# Reference request for a special product

Tags: reference-request, products

I have the product $$\prod_{k=0}^n (1+a_k)$$ Does this product have a special name under which I can find some of its properties? I appreciate any reference for this product.

Note: Because of the inequality $1+x \le e^x$ I have already found the inequality $$\prod_{k=0}^n (1+a_k) \le \exp(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k)$$ if $\forall k \in \{0\ldots n\}: a_k \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since given a product $\prod_i a_i$ setting $a_i' = a_i - 1$ will transform it in a product $\prod_i (1 + a_i')$ there is nothing special about that type of product without further restrictions.

That being said, the form you gave is common when considering [infinite products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product), among others due to the  inequality you mentioned that helps to establish that $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1 + a_i)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}  a_i$ converges.